# Jar write file zero byte sized when execute as nobody user

Tags: java, php, linux, user-permissions

I have to execute a java program from PHP, I'm doing this with:

```
exec("java -jar protected/data/myProgram.jar", $output, $return_var);
```

the problem is that the .jar write a pdf, but the file has a size of zero byte.

I have controlled that user have permission to write in the folder. The program doesn't throw any error. (I can see the system out).

Anybody have experience in executing Jar that write file as nobody user in linux?

Comment: Has the Java user the permission to write?

Comment: Yes. Directory has 777 permission.

Comment: For all group users? But i think that the answer can help you solve your problem.

Comment: Can you run the program yourself from the command line and make it work?

Comment: If I run from the commad line, it works. But I think that the reason is that I don't execute as user nobody. If I execute as nobody from the command line, the resulting pdf has size zero.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it shows the file at all suggests it has access permissions to write. Maybe it can't see the data. You need to add logging into your program so you can see what it is doing and any errors produced and either display the messages on the website or save the log somewhere you can see it so you can go find the cause of the error.

Comment: I have put all the code beetween try/catch statement, but no error is raised.

Comment: Logging doesn't just mean try catch. Check your assumption, add debug statements in your code to verify them. Think of what could be going wrong and test the theory until you find something that is going wrong, then if it still doesn't work repeat the process.